# Am I "available for hire"?

Tags: word-choice

Me and my mother had a long discussion yesterday about when you are allowed to write that you are "available for hire".

At the moment I am sending out job applications, and I end them by saying that I am "available for hire" but my mother says that you can't write it like that, since you can't be "for hire" when you're looking for a full-time job only. She says that "for hire" is only for smaller tasks or jobs.

What do you think?
What could be a good alternative, if necessary?

Comment: A clearer alternative might be "I am available for an immediate start"

Comment: You may write "I am [currently/actively] looking for work" (or "for a job"). And as suggested by @ MarvMills, you may add "and I am available for an immediate start".

Comment: I think your mother is correct. "For hire" does make it sound like it's for an individual job, such as a plumbing job or a DJ-ing job. I agree with @MarvMills's suggestion.

Comment: The problem with putting "available for hire" on a resume has nothing to do with it being a phrase used strictly for short term jobs (it just happens to be that).  The problem is that it's horribly redundant.  Why would anyone send out resumes if they weren't "available for hire"?

Comment: It's a longer story, but I have developed a video game, and in the ending there is a screen where it says "Available for hire". I have replaced it with "Available for an immediate start"

Comment: I would omit the statement. If you are sending a resume to a prospective employer, your *general* availability is implicit, making the statement redundant. If the issue is about the relative immediacy of your availability, such an issue would almost surely arise in an interview or immediately following a job offer.

Comment: "For hire" has different meanings in different contexts and cultures.  It's hard to pin down when it might be appropriate for you.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative could be "I am prepared to be hired as an active employee."